# **polygon.setfillcolor(Color)** not working for google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, polygons

I am adding a Polygon into Google Map v2 like this:

```
for (int index = coordinats.size()-1; index >= 0; index--) {
        polygonOptions.add(
                new LatLng(latCoordinats.get(index), lngCoordinats.get(index)));
    }
     polygonOptions.strokeColor(0x7FFFFFFF);
     polygonOptions.strokeWidth((float) 5);
     polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);

     polygon=   mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
```

> polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);

is not working for me...
What am i missing?

Comment: Can you try to use [`setFillColor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html#setFillColor%28int%29) instead, and check if that works? It might have something to do with `PolygonOptions`.

Comment: Yes , I tried this. but not work

Comment: For me this started after updating to Android 4.4.2, but it only happens for my larges polygons, the small ones are still filled??

Comment: that because there is hole in middle. check on your map there is an island that filled by blue color. Iam facing same problem please let me know if you know the answer

Answer (score 1):

I am also tried **polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);** and **polygon.setFillColor(color);** it has no effect for random latitude and longitude coordinates.

I Tested by giving only four corners latitude and longitude coordinates 
new LatLng(-31.673, 128.892),
                        new LatLng(-31.952, 115.857),
                        new LatLng(-17.785, 122.258),
                        new LatLng(-12.4258, 130.7932)
**polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.BLUE);** is working